# unable to find install package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been attempting to install diamondback.

I enter "sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full"

and get

"unable to locate package ros-diamondback-desktop-full"

I am completely new to linux, so any help would be greatly appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9735/unable-to-find-install-package/) by [Dave Everett](https://answers.ros.org/users/427/dave-everett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2011-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After adding the ROS repositories to your apt sources and adding the WillowGarage keys (steps 1.2 and 1.3 of the [Ubuntu installation guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu)), make sure you also run `sudo apt-get update` (beginning of step 1.4).

`sudo apt-get update` will instruct apt to refresh it's list of available software to take into account the fact that you just added new repositories.

After this, you should be able to run `sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full` with no problems.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just found I needed to update again after enabling universe and multiverse, it is now installing.

Dave

---

Originally posted by [Dave Everett](https://answers.ros.org/users/427/dave-everett/) with karma: 48 on 2011-04-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1